# Writing the sequence backwards

Tags: logic, recurrence-relations, recursion, computability, recursive-algorithms

Let $\pi^{(n)}: \mathbb N^n\to \mathbb N$ be [the Cantor tuple function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function). So $\pi^{(2)}$ is the Cantor pairing function. Let $\mathbb N^\ast$ be the set of finite sequences of natural numbers (a sequence is written as $\langle n_1,\dots, n_k\rangle$) and let $p:\mathbb N^\ast\to\mathbb N$ be the function $$p(\epsilon)=\pi^{(2)}(0,0)\\ p(\langle n_1,\dots, n_k\rangle)=\pi^{(2)}(k-1, \pi^{(k)}(\langle n_1,\dots, n_k\rangle)) \text { for } k\ge 1$$

Suppose we know that there exists a (computable) function $sum:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N,\ sum(p(\langle n_1,\dots, n_k\rangle))=\sum_{i=1}^k n_i$. How to deduce that there is also a computable function $backwards:\mathbb N\to \mathbb N$
such that $backwards: p(\langle n_1,\dots, n_k\rangle)\mapsto p(\langle n_k,\dots, n_1\rangle)$?

I think one needs to use somehow the fact that $sum(p(\langle n_1,\dots, n_k\rangle))=n_1+\dots+n_k=\\ n_k+\dots+n_1=sum(p(\langle n_k,\dots, n_1\rangle))$

but this symmetry doesn't tell me much about the function $backwards$.

Comment: I don't think the sum function is going to help you here (unless there's some clever way to use it that I'm missing). Instead, you probably need to show from scratch that the backwards function is computable. And how to do this depends heavily on what your precise definition of computable function is.

Comment: Why are you "supposing" any of this? Is $$\left\lfloor \dfrac{\sqrt{8z - 1}-1}2\right\rfloor$$ not computable for some reason that I don't see? Doesn't both the existence of $sum$ and of $backward$ follow easily from the invertibility of the pairing function?

Comment: @PaulSinclair If it's an easy argument, could you explain how the existence of sum and backwards follow from the invertibility of the pairing function?

Comment: I assumed I was overlooking something. But if that is what the problem is, I've added an answer summarizing it.

Answer (score 1):

Per this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Inverting_the_Cantor_pairing_function), the pairing function $\pi^{(2)} : \Bbb N^2 \to \Bbb N$ is invertible, and therefore a bijection. $\pi^{(1)} : \Bbb N \to \Bbb N : k \mapsto k$ is also a bijection.

For $n > 2$, suppose $\pi^{(n-1)}$ is a bijection. Then the map $$k \overset {{\pi^{(2)}}^{-1}}\mapsto (\alpha, k_n)\overset {{\pi^{(n-1)}}^{-1}\times id } \mapsto (\langle k_1, k_2, ..., k_{n-1}\rangle, k_n)\mapsto \langle k_1, k_2, ..., k_{n-1}, k_n\rangle$$
defines an inverse for $\pi^{(n)}$, which is therefore a bijection.

I assume $\epsilon$ is the empty sequence. Then the map
$$k \overset {{\pi^{(2)}}^{-1}}\mapsto \langle k_1, k_2\rangle \mapsto {\pi^{(k_1+1)}}^{-1}(k_2) $$
Is an inverse function for the restriction of $p$ to $\Bbb N^* \setminus \{\epsilon\}$. On the other hand, $$p(\epsilon) = p(\langle 0 \rangle) = 0$$

So, $$sum(k) = \sum_{i=1}^{|p^{-1}(k)|} (p^{-1}(k))_i$$
and $$backwards(k) = p(rev(p^{-1}(k))$$
where $rev(\langle k_1, ..., k_n\rangle) := \langle k_n, ..., k_1\rangle$.

The only place where computability seems even slightly questionable is in this step of computing the inverse of $\pi^{(2)}$:
$$z \mapsto \left\lfloor \dfrac{\sqrt{8z - 1}-1}2\right\rfloor$$
I'm no expert on computability, but it seems computable to me. And all the rest is just a finite (for any given input) application of functions known to be computable.

Now there is that small detail of $p(\epsilon) = p(\langle 0 \rangle)$, but can you see why it makes no difference to $sum$ and $backwards$?

Comment: Why is $rev$ computable? It looks like it's a function $\mathbb N^\ast\to \mathbb N^\ast$; we don't have the notion of computability for such functions, so we need to use $p$ (and its inverse) to transform this $rev$ function to a function between natural numbers, then prove its computability, and use it instead of $rev$.

Comment: *rev* is just reversing the order of a finite sequence. Any Turing machine can handle it for any size input. If that doesn't qualify as computable, then I'm curious what would. But I know very little about computable functions, so anything I say about them is more than suspect. So the computability side of this is not something I can address.